# how to extend scope of some variable in anonymous inner class

Tags: java, final

I've an anonymous class :

```
filepath.putFile(userItemPhotoUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
   Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading finished ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

I want to extend the scope of downloadUri to its outer block.

I tried but I failed to do so.
Declaring a final variable in the outer block will not work because we can't initialize it again inside.

Comment: You could always just avoid using anonymous inner classes, and inject some kind of object that you want to modify into your class that was once inner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I would recommend using a "Holder" class that will help with storing values. It's a very useful mechanism that allows you to access data. Personally, I [don't think that having public scoped variables are a good idea](http://xkcdsw.com/1394).

So you could have a holder type object with getters/setters to hold :

```
public class HoldThis {

    private Uri downloadUri;

    public void setUri(Uri uri){
        this.downloadUri = uri;
    }

    public Uri getUri(){
        return downloadUri;
    }

}
```

You also have the option to do something like the following:

Outer class: `final Uri []uri = new Uri[1];` and then you can modify this in the inner class by just doing `uri[0] =  taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();`

Comment: the second options is clean and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem: it isn't that easy. You see, the idea of an anonymous inner class is that it might be "decoupled" from its outer context. That is the reason why you have to make local variables **final** when using them internally.

The "normal" way of resolving that: add a **field** to the enclosing class, like:

```
public class YourClass ... {
  private Uri downloadUri;
```

and now your inner class can read+modify that field *downloadUri*.

O, as Ayushin suggested: you could as well call a method of your enclosing class, and provide that locally created Uri object as parameter. In the end, "whats right" very much depends on your overall context/design.

Comment: how about calling a function and passing variable as the parameter of the function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a member field on which you set the value of the downloadUri. You can't set it in the method which holds the above code since that stack frame will be erased from memory once the method finishes.